# iterate over model columns

Tags: python, django

How do i loop over all fields from a `QuerySet`. I need a list of all field values to export to a xlsx file but the columns can not be predefined with `client.name` for example.

If for loop objects, i just get the ID:

```
for i in Model.objects.all():
    print i
```

If i try to nest for loops, i get `TypeError 'Model' object is not iterable`.

```
for i in Model.objects.all():
        for y in i:
            print y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for obj in Model.objects.all():
    for field in obj._meta.get_all_field_names():
        print getattr(obj, field)
```

However if you export to csv/xlsx, I won't recommend doing that, because there might be some fields that are `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`, etc, so it's better to do it explicitly for each field.

Edit:

I just tried it myself but you might need `getattr(obj, field, None)` to show `None` on some of the fields that are empty, like `OneToOneField`.